# Hide "more jobs at Company X" when there are no more jobs

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs

QuikOrder has one job: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/129929/node-engineer-quikorder?offset=1&

But if you scroll to the bottom of the page it shows a link that says "more jobs at QuikOrder >":

[image]

But clicking this link leads to this:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?cpg=quikorder

Which tells you `thats a miss`

Can we disable or hide this link if there are no other jobs for Company X?

Comment: Alternatively if there are no more jobs maybe take the person to the company page (jobs) section instead of the search company page.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your feedback.  I cannot currently reproduce this issue.  However, it seems likely that you stumbled on a race condition in which the company posted two jobs about the same time, and the search index had not quite been updated to include those jobs yet when searching by company (which is what that link effectively does).

The "more jobs at (Company)" link already should not appear for companies with only one current job posting.

Comment: Well now this company has more jobs - yesterday when I did this it only had one job so this issue appeared...I swear yesterday there was an issue!  I don't know what changed but maybe it is what you say happened.